# How to return a default value in an Async Pipe Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following pipe that returns value from a firebase function. The firebase function sometimes is slow to return back a value.

So instead of showing a blank empty space while waiting for firebase functions, I want to return a default value back to the view that will only be updated when firebase functions response.

Here is the pipe:

```
export class dataPipe  implements PipeTransform {
        constructor(private _firebaseFunctionsSer: SharedService) {}
        transform(status: any): any {
           ...
            if(status){

                return this._firebaseFunctionsSer.getData(status);
           }
        }

}
```

Here is the getData(status) service function:

```
getData(data){
       ....
        return this.http.post<any>(url, {data: data}).pipe(map(result => result.result));
    }
```

And this is how it's called in the view:

```
<div [innerHTML]="status.status | data | async"></div>
```

So, how can I return a default value in this instance, I want to return the default status value.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but if you want the pipe to be returning the default value, maybe your pipe can have its own observable which fires first with a default value, and then with the firebase response. Alternatively, this article shows how to accomplish what you want, but without the pipe knowing the default value: https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe

Comment: That said, are you sure you want a pipe to be returning async data?

Comment: Is there any other way, rather than returning async data? If there is, then I will go for it.

Comment: I don't know your use case, but I'd think a component should be requesting the data. That component would have a property like `isLoaded` to know when the data has been received, and would display things accordingly. (Or it could do what's done in that article).

Comment: Nice idea! I thought I could just deal with it pipe side without having to involve the component class.

Comment: If you need this to be reusable you could have all this in a small component class. But generally, I like to keep data access in the highest level components.

Comment: Thanks! I should consider doing so too.